# Entityframework core does not generate an Update statement despite entry.IsModified = true

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Although I set 2 properties as "dirty" they get not save to the database.

Well there is no Update Statement created at all...

What do I wrong?

```
var modifiedTestTypesToUpdate = testTypes.Except(testTypesToAdd.Concat(testTypesToRemove).ToList(), new TestTypeComparer()).ToList();
foreach (var testType in modifiedTestTypesToUpdate)
{
    var entry = context.Entry(testType);
    entry.Property(p => p.Name).IsModified = true;
    entry.Property(p => p.Weight).IsModified = true;
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync(); 

public class TestType
{
    public TestType()
    {
        Tests = new HashSet<Test>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public ISet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }  
    public Schoolclass Schoolclass { get; set; }
    public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
}

 modelBuilder.Entity<TestType>().HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.Name, x.SchoolclassId, x.SubjectId });
```

**UPDATE**

As it was suggest to set the State of the entry to State.Modified then I replied that I tried this before having the problem, that navigation properties on that entity also get marked as modified which result in that **Exception**:

```
  var modifiedTestTypesToUpdate = testTypes.Except(testTypesToAdd.Concat(testTypesToRemove).ToList(), new TestTypeComparer()).ToList();
            foreach (var testType in modifiedTestTypesToUpdate)
            {
                testType.Schoolclass = schoolclass; // Exception occurs here firstly
                testType.Subject = subject;
                testType.Schoolyear = schoolyear;
                var entry = context.Entry(testType).State = EntityState.Modified;

            }
```

**Exception**:

Error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'SchoolclassId' on entity type 'TestType' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.`

If I do not assign those 3 navigation properties to the test type then I would get **another Exception** like:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TestTypes_Schoolyears_SchoolyearId". The conflict occurred in database "TGBData", table "dbo.Schoolyears", column 'Id'.
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TestTypes_Schoolyears_SchoolyearId". The conflict occurred in database "TGBData", table "dbo.Schoolyears", column 'Id'.
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TestTypes_Schoolyears_SchoolyearId". The conflict occurred in database "TGBData", table "dbo.Schoolyears", column 'Id'.
```

**UPDATE**

Now that my Update Statement works after doing the attaching of the 3 nav props just before the Savechanges I get this generated Update statement:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[@p2='?', @p0='?', @p1='?', @p5='?', @p3='?', @p4='?', @p8='?', @p6='?', @p7='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [TestTypes] SET [SchoolyearId] = @p0, [Weight] = @p1
WHERE [Id] = @p2;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
UPDATE [TestTypes] SET [SchoolyearId] = @p3, [Weight] = @p4
WHERE [Id] = @p5;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
UPDATE [TestTypes] SET [SchoolyearId] = @p6, [Weight] = @p7
WHERE [Id] = @p8;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

WHY on earth is that Name field not included in the Update statement?

Comment: I assume you entity has a key also you need to mark it as entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: This approach of marking the whole entity`s state as Modified I used before. I do not want this because I have navigation properties added to the testType entities and I can Not set those nav props as modified. This error I got is an example: System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'SchoolclassId' on entity type 'TestType' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified

Comment: I updated my question with more information!

Comment: Are these entities already being tracked in the context?

Comment: yes all 3 navigation properties are tracked via context.Attach(...)

Comment: OK I put the attaching of the nav props just before the SaveChanges what solved my problem! One little error is still that only the field Weight is updated, but thefield Name NOT! This field is not in the Update statement,how can this be?

Comment: I opened a new question about the update statement which I think is a total different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181553/he-instance-of-entity-type-testtype-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance