# The instance of entity type 'TestType' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting the below exception when I try to do:

```
    context.Entry(testType).State = EntityState.Modified;


System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'TestType' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)
```

I do not see any code where another TestType instance with a same key is already tracked!

The testtypes from the database are loaded via `.AsNoTracking();`

So where in this code are instances of TestType with the same key where I do an RemoveRange/AddRange operation on? That would mean that my TestTypeComparer is broken?

What I try to do here is to let the user **batch save changed/add/deleted entities in one go:**

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TestType>> SaveTestTypesAsync(List<TestType> testTypes, int schoolyearId, int schoolclassId, int subjectId)
        {
            var testTypesFromDatabase = await context.TestTypes
                                          .Include(t => t.Subject)
                                          .Include(s => s.Schoolclass)
                                          .Where(p =>
                                          p.Schoolclass.Id == schoolclassId &&
                                          p.Subject.Id == subjectId)
                                          .AsNoTracking()
                                          .ToListAsync();

            var schoolclass = new Schoolclass { Id = schoolclassId };
            var subject = new Subject { Id = subjectId };
            var schoolyear = new Schoolyear { Id = schoolyearId };
            foreach (var testType in testTypes)
            {
                testType.Schoolclass = schoolclass;
                testType.Subject = subject;
                testType.Schoolyear = schoolyear;
            }

            var testTypesToRemove = testTypesFromDatabase.Except(testTypes, new TestTypeComparer()).ToList();
            context.TestTypes.RemoveRange(testTypesToRemove);

            var testTypesToAdd = testTypes.Where(t => t.Id == 0).ToList();  // 
            context.TestTypes.AddRange(testTypesToAdd);

            var modifiedTestTypesToUpdate = testTypes.Except(testTypesToAdd.Concat(testTypesToRemove).ToList(), new TestTypeComparer()).ToList();
            foreach (var testType in modifiedTestTypesToUpdate)
            {
                context.Entry(testType).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            context.Attach(schoolclass);      
            context.Attach(subject);
            context.Attach(schoolyear);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return await this.GetTestTypesConfigurationAsync(schoolclassId, subjectId);
        }


public class TestTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestType>
{
    public bool Equals(TestType x, TestType y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TestType obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class TestType
    {
        public TestType()
        {
            Tests = new HashSet<Test>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public ISet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        public Schoolyear Schoolyear { get; set; }  
        public Schoolclass Schoolclass { get; set; }
        public int SchoolclassId { get; set; }
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public int SchoolyearId { get; set; }
    }
```

*Anyone can help me please I can`t spot the double tracked entity with same key.*

*I just assume the problem has something to do how I determine the Added/Modified/Deleted entities.*

**UPDATE**

I have now logged all the tracker changes just before I set the State.Modified for all TestTypesToUpdate:

```
State: Deleted | Type: TestType | Id-Value: 12
State: Unchanged | Type: Schoolclass | Id-Value: 1
State: Unchanged | Type: TestType | Id-Value: 8
State: Unchanged | Type: Subject | Id-Value: 1
State: Deleted | Type: TestType | Id-Value: 13
State: Added | Type: TestType | Id-Value: -2147482647
State: Detached | Type: Schoolclass | Id-Value: 1
State: Added | Type: Schoolyear | Id-Value: 1
State: Detached | Type: Subject | Id-Value: 1
State: Added | Type: TestType | Id-Value: -2147482646
```

It seems yeah ... some entities are already tracked. Seems I have to invest some more if/else with the change tracker and then decide what to do.

But I can not believe that I am the first doing something like that, havent found anything on google.

Comment: IMO this is because of Context. You should dispose and re-initialize in every query. But you use the same context more than once.

Comment: What means use more than once technically in your opinion? Do you speak about the Get call at the end of the method? I can remove that Get Call without any affect.

Comment: "context.TestTypes" where is that context from? is "context" new every time you call it? [Dispose](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

Comment: This context is injected in the Repository Constructor per http call. Its just created ONE time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about *multiple instances with same key* problem I rearranged the code a bit again until I got the error again, that I can not set the state of testTypeToUpdate to state.Modified because SchoolclassId is part of a key.

Well... then I searched in my fluent migrations and found this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestType>().HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.Name, x.SchoolclassId, x.SubjectId });
```

I did this a while ago (but never tested it - shame on me -) and I thought its the EF6 equivalent to the Index Attribute... Because thats the feature I wanted!

Then I googled and created something new:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestType>().HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.SchoolclassId, p.SubjectId} ).IsUnique();
```

Now I have what I wanted!

I also removed the assigned of the schoolclass, subject and schoolyear instance to the testTypesToRemove that also created some weird stuff...

That code works now:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<TestType>> SaveTestTypesAsync(List<TestType> testTypes, int schoolyearId, int schoolclassId, int subjectId)
        {
            var testTypesFromDatabase = await context.TestTypes
                                          .Include(t => t.Subject)
                                          .Include(s => s.Schoolclass)
                                          .Where(p =>
                                          p.Schoolclass.Id == schoolclassId &&
                                          p.Subject.Id == subjectId)
                                          .AsNoTracking()
                                          .ToListAsync();

            var schoolclass = new Schoolclass { Id = schoolclassId };
            var subject = new Subject { Id = subjectId };
            var schoolyear = new Schoolyear { Id = schoolyearId };

            // Make the navigation properties available during SaveChanges()
            context.Attach(schoolclass);
            context.Attach(subject);
            context.Attach(schoolyear);

            // DELETE
            var testTypesToRemove = testTypesFromDatabase.Except(testTypes, new TestTypeComparer()).ToList();
            context.TestTypes.RemoveRange(testTypesToRemove);

            // ADD
            var testTypesToAdd = testTypes.Where(t => t.Id == 0).ToList();  // 
            foreach (var testType in testTypesToAdd)
            {
                testType.Schoolclass = schoolclass;
                testType.Subject = subject;
                testType.Schoolyear = schoolyear;
            }
            context.TestTypes.AddRange(testTypesToAdd);

            // UPDATE
            var modifiedTestTypesToUpdate = testTypes.Except(testTypesToAdd.Concat(testTypesToRemove).ToList(), new TestTypeComparer()).ToList();
            foreach (var testType in modifiedTestTypesToUpdate)
            {
                testType.Schoolclass = schoolclass;
                testType.Subject = subject;
                testType.Schoolyear = schoolyear;
            }   
            context.UpdateRange(modifiedTestTypesToUpdate);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return await this.GetTestTypesConfigurationAsync(schoolclassId, subjectId);
        }
```